# Entity framework performs an update of navigational property object's timestamp when it is assigned to parent object

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity framework problem I'm currently grappling with. I've searched for questions relating to my issue but haven't been able to find related ones. If you know of any similar questions already asked, appreciate you pointing me to it.

My problem arises from a web app I'm currently developing for my organization. Due to the planned public usage, the web app has limited SQL permissions, restricting select, insert, and update to the only tables actually needed. One of those tables is the Users table which track who is allowed to use the app, the web app only has Select permission on that table.

As part of the web app's purpose, the accessing user can create forms and assign ownership to that form. The owner can be the creator himself or some another existing user in the User table. The owner is represented as a navigation property on the form entity.

Assigning ownership is just a simple matter of selecting from a HTML select list representing users and user ids. Then the foreign user ID on the form entity being created (on the server) is set to the ID representing the chosen user owner. The form entity is added to the database context and the SaveChanges method is called to persist the new form to the Form table in the database along with the owner foreign key set to point to the relevant row in the User table, basically your typical standard creation scenario.

What happens next varies, I haven't been able to determine the exact circumstances causing it to sometimes fail. Sometimes the save is successful, other times it fails with an error message saying that the Entity Framework attempted to perform an update on the Users table which fails since it does not have Update permission. Using the SQL Profiler, I see that an update statement was generated that attempts to update the timestamp column of the user row representing the form's owner.

Obviously this problem would go away if I granted Update permission to the web app, but there is no reason why it should be able to update the User table, and it shouldn't be required. If I just grant it, it would open up a potential security hole. My question is why does Entity Framework attempts to update the timestamp column of the navigational property after it's attached to the form entity? This only fails occasionally, suggesting that sometimes it's decided it's not necessary to update the timestamp of the user owner. The user being attached to the form being created isn't modified in any way, it's just an number assigned to the foreign key property on the form entity.

Color me perplexed. Hopefully you have an idea of what's going on and how I can work around it.

Appreciate your insights.